# Error in Word 2007 page setup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2007

I am not sure what the issue may be, but I am getting a weird error in Word 2007 (running on Win7 pro x86).  When I click the page setup button (or try and chnage one of the page formatiing button like orientation) the program stops responding and crashes on me.  This is really getting annoying.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the error says? what it does? picture of it?

Comment: Can you share the document that made weird errors?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to say, but in situations like this I've found that since the MS applications touch the printer driver on page operations, the problem could be the printer driver.  You might want to uninstall it or install PDFCreator (which installs a virtual printer driver) to hold the place of the printer and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by a reboot.  I am not sure what caused it, but it could have been memory corruption.  Thank you guys for your help though.